# Creating jQuery Validation rules using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validation plugin.  Per, http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method, a callback is used to send extra data (i.e. username).

```
var myObj={
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: "check-email.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    username: function() {
                        return $( "#username" ).val();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

$( "#myform" ).validate(myObj);
```

Works perfect!  But now, I don't wish to hardcode the `myObj` object, but use PHP to create it.  Note that my example script below is extra simple and doesn't address the validation plugin.

One way to do so is to directly create the JavaScript as I did so for `myObj1`.  However, I have been told that one should never dynamically create JavaScript using PHP due to security and troubleshooting issues.  Instead, I should just pass JSON from the server to the client.

So, I tried to do so for `myObj2`, however, evidently JSON cannot contain JavaScript, and it doesn't parses.

What is the best way to dynamically create jQuery Validation rules using PHP?

```
<?php
$myID='myID';
if(isset($_GET['task'])) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    exit("{'data':{'getValue':function() {return $( '#{$myID}' ).val();}}}");
}
else {
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
        console.log(window,location);
            <?php echo("var myObj1={'data':{'getValue':function() {return $( '#{$myID}' ).val();}}}");?>

            $(function() {
                alert(myObj1.data.getValue());

                $.get(location.href+'?task=getJSON',function (myObj2){
                    alert(myObj2.data.getValue());
                    },'json');

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="myID" type="text" value="Hello" />
    </body>
</html>

    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I have to ask. *why* do you need to use php to create this? it doesn't make much sense from my perspective.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy.  I have my own PHP class which server-side validates the data.  It also has the ability to create the jQuery validation plugin object.  This way, I do not have to maintain two sets of validation script.

Comment: So just use `echo` to construct the page with the correct values in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"What is the best way to dynamically create jQuery Validation rules using PHP?"*

There is no "best" way.  Since the PHP constructs the page (incl the JavaScript) on the server and the jQuery Validation plugin only runs in the browser, I don't understand your issue.  How could using JavaScript's `ajax` to retrieve the parameters be more secure than just using a PHP `echo` to put those parameters into the page in the first place, *before* it's sent to the browser?

No matter how you construct your page, the JavaScript code will/should look exactly the same when it gets to the browser.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#myform" ).validate( <?php echo .... ;?> );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So, you feel it is okay to use PHP to dynamically create JS?

Comment: @user1032531, why wouldn't it be? All PHP is executed on the server where the page is fully constructed *before* being sent to the browser. From the browser's perspective, it's no different than a static HTML file.

Comment: I create jQuery all the time dynamically with PHP, and I have a specific class that creates form validation rules and messages so I know by experience it works fine.

Comment: Possible to show a snippet of how you construct this as I am getting headaches?

Comment: @MikeMiller, there is nothing more to show you, and the code "snippets" feature is not for PHP.  This answer is generically explaining how to use PHP to write the object literal for the JavaScript when the page is constructed.  If you have a problem, [please post it as a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), so you can get specific help.

Comment: Yeah I am doing now. I didnt quite follow the snippets feature point possibly having a terminology clash. No worries though I will post, thanks

Comment: @MikeMiller, the "code snippets" feature is for embedding JavaScript-HTML-CSS directly into the posting for a working demo.  Even if that's not what you meant, there's nothing more to show here that is relevant to the OP's question.  Thanks.

Comment: OK gotcha I was using the term in a more general sense